# Where is the object in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> I’m getting answers from her.

What is `from her` in this sentence? Is it indirect object?

Comment: "Answers" is the direct object of "getting". The preposition phrase "from her" is not indirect object but complement of "getting".

Comment: @BillJ: I think it's true to say ***to get*** can be "bivalent" with, say, *I'm getting John answers*. And although I can't think of any really credible examples, I'm inclined to think that if I had to make sense of *I'm **John** getting answers,* I'd identify John as the *source* of the answers, not the intended *recipient*. Maybe I'm imagining a hyphenated verb ***John-getting***, but it does seem *almost* credible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*From her* is a preposition phrase; its precise syntactic role is complicated.

- It is certainly **not** an indirect object, which is semantically a Recipient or Beneficiary of the action and syntactically must (in most contemporary grammars) be a noun phrase rather than a preposition phrase.
- Traditional grammar would probably call it an 'adverbial phrase' modifying the verb *am getting* or the verb phrase *am getting answers*—what many contemporary grammars call an 'adjunct'.
- Semantically it is a locative designating the Origin of the answers; I am inclined to understand it as an optional complement of *get*, which as a verb of at least figurative motion—information 'moves' from the Answerer to the Asker—licenses any number of PP designating Origin, Trajectory and Goal.
- And it's *just* possible to regard it as an 'adjectival' PP modifying *answers*. I don't think that's the case here, but in another context, such as "The answers from her are more than adequate", it would be.

Comment: I's take it as a source complement.

Comment: @BillJ Yah, there's variability in the terminology: Source/Origin, Path/Trajectory, Goal/Target. I tend to use the more 'spatial' terms, because I think of the non-spatial versions as metaphors. But mostly I just pick the first one that comes to mind!